# mycursor.executemany UPDATE not working as expected

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

## Question:

I have a python script to scrape and website it gets 2 variables and stores them in 2 lists. I then use executemany to update MySQL database using one variable to match a pre-existing row to insert the other variable into.

## Code:

#### Python Script

```
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time, re

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="host",
  user="user",
  passwd="passwd",
  database="database"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

d = webdriver.Chrome('D:/Uskompuf/Downloads/chromedriver')
d.get('https://au.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/overall-list/#page=1')
def cpus(_source):
  result = soup(_source, 'html.parser').find('ul', {'id':'category_content'}).find_all('li')
  _titles = list(filter(None, [(lambda x:'' if x is None else x.text)(i.find('div', {'class':'title'})) for i in result]))
  data = [list(filter(None, [re.findall('(?<=\().*?(?=\))', c.text) for c in i.find_all('div')])) for i in result]
  return _titles, [a for *_, [a] in filter(None, data)]


_titles, _cpus = cpus(d.page_source)
sql = "UPDATE cpu set family = %s where name = %s"
mycursor.executemany(sql, list(zip(_cpus, _titles)))
print(sql, list(zip(_titles, _cpus)))
_last_page = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('#page\=\d+')})[-1].text
for i in range(2, int(_last_page)+1):
   d.get(f'https://au.pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/overall-list/#page={i}') 
   time.sleep(3)
   _titles, _cpus = cpus(d.page_source)
   sql = "UPDATE cpu set family = %s where name = %s"
   mycursor.executemany(sql, list(zip(_cpus, _titles)))

mydb.commit()
```

#### MySQL UPDATE code

```
sql = "UPDATE cpu set family = %s where name = %s"
mycursor.executemany(sql, list(zip(_cpus, _titles)))
```

#### MySQL UPDATE code print

```
print(sql, list(zip(_cpus, _titles)))
```

#### MySQL UPDATE code print output

```
UPDATE cpu set family = %s where name = %s [('Pinnacle Ridge', 'AMD Ryzen 5 2600'), ('Coffee Lake-S', 'Intel Core i7-8700K'),...
```

## First 2 rows of table

[image]

## Expected result

The first variable is the name and that is the variable that needs to be matched the second variable is the family to be updated to row. The name matches perfectly and there are no errors when running the program however all family values are null.

Not sure what the best way to go solving this, I though i could make a fiddle but not sure about the list in executemany?

## Other

If you need any more information please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Can i ask a question? There are any name's value is `Pinnacle Ridge`. Because i ran a small example like `cur.executemany("UPDATE test SET col = %s WHERE col = %s", [("a","1"),("b","2")])`, it works well.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure i completely understand the name values are AMD Ryzen 5 2600, Intel Core i7-8700k etc the family are Pinnacle Ridge, Coffe-Lake-S. Im not sure if the order is incorrect if so how can i rearrange it?

Comment: I think you should fix your question, what you printed and what you used in executemany are different.

Comment: Actually, your situation confused me. I created a similar table and insert all value in `_titles` first. Then use part of your code(before for-loop), i got what you desire `| AMD Ryzen 5 2600                 | Pinnacle Ridge      |
| Intel Core i7-8700K              | Coffee Lake-S       |
| AMD Ryzen 7 2700X                | Pinnacle Ridge      |
| AMD Ryzen 3 2200G                | Raven Ridge         |`

Comment: sorry im not sure what you mean i am trying the achieve the families being matched to the rows by the names? Do you know what i need to change in my code to achieve this?

Comment: ohh i just noticed the problem with the print statement ill update it

Comment: ok so i updated the print statement and the output so now im just puzzled why its not working?

Comment: fixed see below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had to add:

```
mydb.commit()
```

after

```
executemany
```